# What dock I can easily configure to have these controls?

Tags: dock

I was trying out docky, and I liked it but i was kinda underwhelmed.
The network connections docklet didn't work, there wasn't a volume control and i couldn't change my keyboard input.
What docks i can easily configure to have these things and works well with Lubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Docks usually don't have such features. Use the default panel instead.

Comment: You could pin the settings menu to the dock. There's tint2 I could suggest, but that works more like a panel instead of dock

Answer (score 1):

Use Cairo-Dock. It has built-in applets for both keyboard and volume control.

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```